# Vue.js 2 How to populate an Vue data in v-for loop without having infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a v-for loop (See code below)

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in elementsList" v-bind:key="element.id">
    <component :config="getConfig(index)"></component>
</div>
```

Here my function getConfig which calculate coordinates, store them in a array and return them

```
methods: {
    getConfig: function(i) {
        const { x, y } = this.calculCoordinates(i)
        this.positionList.push({ x, y }); // If I delete this line, I have no infinite loop

        return  {
            points: [
                x,
                y,
            ],
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 2
        } 
    },
}
```

With my code I have an infinite loop. Indeed the line which push the object `{ x, y }` re-render the view and start again and again my v-for loop.

How can I populate an Vue data without having an infinite loop ?

Comment: is positionList a vue prop or data ?

Comment: positionList is a Vue data, that's why Vue re render because the value is changed. But how can change a data inside a v-for loop whithout creating an infinite loop ?

Comment: How does positionList relate to elementList, and why are you doing this in a UI rendering loop?

Comment: Should `positionList` have the same length as `elementList`? `v-for` is not a good place to modify data. Does `calculCoordinates` use `elementList`'s elements?